# Did a Cypriot bishop claim that homosexuality is caused when parents have anal sex?

Tags: quotes, sexuality, christianity, cyprus

The August 1, 2019 issue of MetroWeekly ("Washington D.C.'s Best LGBTQ Magazine for 25 Years"), on page 46, provides a "LastWord" quotation section that includes the following:

> "Gays are created due [to] the anal sex of a straight couple and only if the woman is into it."
>
> -THE MOST REVEREND METROPOLITAN NEOPHYTOS (MASOURAS) OF MORFOU OF THE CHURCH OF CYPRUS, arguing in a YouTube video - translated by LGBTQ Cypriot group Accept - that women who enjoy anal sex while pregnant give birth to gay children.
>
> "If that happens, the feeling of pleasure the woman feels is transmitted to the unborn child," he said.

No other particular source is claimed by the magazine column (no date, no video link, etc.).

Is this an accurate translation of something that Metropolitan Neophytos of the Church of Cyprus stated?

Comment: Reputedly [this is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgapuDCo1Zc). I don't speak the lingo, so I cannot verify, but perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The claim is true (that he said it, not what he said)

Here is a link from a Greek news website with the video and a full quote

https://www.in.gr/2019/07/26/greece/mitropolitis-oi-gay-genniountai-apo-ton-proktiko-erota-straight-zeygariou/

> «Οι gay γεννιούνται κατά την ώρα του πρωκτικού έρωτα ενός straight
>   ζευγαριού, και μόνο αν αρέσει στη γυναίκα. Τότε, η επιθυμία αυτή
>   μεταφέρεται στο έμβρυο. Κι αυτό είναι επιστημονικώς αποδεδειγμένο»

My translation is (I speak Greek natively and have a C2 level English language certificate. I translated the quote before I looked at the Google translate version)

> "Gays are born during anal sex of a straight couple, and only if the
>   woman likes it. Then this desire is transferred to the fetus. And this
>   is scientifically proven."

And this is how Google Translate translates the quote

> "Gays are born at the time of anal sex of a straight couple, and only
>   if the woman likes it. This desire is then transferred to the fetus.
>   And this is scientifically proven. "

Comment: Good answer +1. I think you don't need to prove your language skills and nobody will complain if you remove the redundant  Google translation.

Comment: Not exactly relevant, but Google did an amazing job with that translation.